# Access other files on Slax flash drive from within Slax

Tags: live-usb, ntfs, slackware

I've made a bootable Slax flash drive in Windows by copying the slax directory to a USB flash drive and running bootinst.bat in slax/boot. It works as expected as I can boot to Slax from the flash drive, however there are other files on that flash drive, apart from slax directory, that I wish to have access to from within Slax. How do I access these files?

To make this thing clear I want to insert a flash drive in Windows, copy some file to the flash drive, and then boot to Slax from that flash drive and have access to that file.

I've tried copying files to root of the flash drive and to slax directory, but Slax does not see them. The USB flash drive is formatted to NTFS.

Comment: Mount the drive after booting slax.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the drive was already mounted at /run/initramfs/memory/data/